# Pass boolean to expected react-element component props in material-ui list-item

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new in React and may be my question will sound stupid...

I have a material-ui list-item component, and I want to make an edit icon was available only to the content owner.

For example:

```
 var rightAction = (this.props.canEdit)?<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>:false;

   <ListItem
      //properties...
        rightIconButton={righAction}
    />
```

Of course, if you go down to the page content is not the owner, at his console, we will see this error:

> Failed prop type: Invalid prop `rightIconButton` of type `boolean`
>   supplied to `ListItem`, expected a single ReactElement.

The question:

**How can we transfer or not to transfer the property, depending on the conditions?**

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you pass `undefined` to a prop, it is equivalent to not passing it at all.

So just change your conditional to:

```
var rightAction = this.props.canEdit ? <IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton> : undefined;
```

You could also make it simpler to read (imho) by breaking it up:

```
var button = (<IconButton><NavigationClose /></IconButton>);
var rightAction = this.props.canEdit ? button : undefined;
```